# Intended way to change object color outline during modal?

Tags: python, scripting, customization

Let's say, when you moving the object (by pressing G)  the outline color would change to white during operation.

[image]

Since I don't know how to achieve that, so i tried to implement that by changing the theme color temporarily during modal operation and restoring back the color on Confirm or Cancel the operation.
its work as expected indeed, however if an unexpected error happens during modal, the color changed will still remain unless changed back manually (or reset) through Preferences.

so I'm wondering if there is any intended (or the best) way to change outline color during modal operation?

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import IntProperty, FloatProperty, FloatVectorProperty


class ModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Move an object with the mouse, example"""
    bl_idname = "object.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal Operator"

    first_mouse_x: IntProperty()
    first_value: FloatProperty()
    
    color: FloatVectorProperty()

    def modal(self, context, event):
        C= bpy.context
        
        if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':
            delta = self.first_mouse_x - event.mouse_x
            context.object.location.x = self.first_value + delta * 0.01

        elif event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':
            C.preferences.themes[0].view_3d.object_active= self.color
            return {'FINISHED'}

        elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            C.preferences.themes[0].view_3d.object_active= self.color
            context.object.location.x = self.first_value
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        C= bpy.context
        self.color= C.preferences.themes[0].view_3d.object_active
        C.preferences.themes[0].view_3d.object_active= (1,0,0)

        if context.object:
            self.first_mouse_x = event.mouse_x
            self.first_value = context.object.location.x

            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "No active object, could not finish")
            return {'CANCELLED'}


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ModalOperator.bl_idname, text=ModalOperator.bl_label)


# Register and add to the "view" menu (required to also use F3 search "Simple Modal Operator" for quick access).
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.modal_operator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Comment: I believe changing it in the theme is the only way to do that. Obviously if your code crashes the code that changes it back will never get run. The only way around that would be to catch the exemptions with a `try:` `except:`